# How to make dired 'adopt' some useful function from Total command

Tags: emacs, dired, total-commander

In total command, Ctrl+B will display **ALL** files in current directory, which will list the files in sub-directorys recursively in the current window.

-- I know in emacs dired, we can hit 'i' which runs 'dired-maybe-insert-subdir' to insert the file list from ONE sub-directory to current dired buffer, so questions is, how to write a function imitate behavior of total command 'insert-all-subdir'?

Another good one from total command is, Ctrl+f10 and Ctrl+f12 will enable us the ability to switch from displaying all and only **some files with certain extension** (such as 'only show me all the *.mp3 files!')

-- My feeling is that maybe we can tweak dired-omit to imitate this one?

Also in total command, one can set a rule to hightlight files (such as show it in red color) which are modified/accessed in 1 day (the date is set by users), which make them easy to be distinguished from those old, long-time-no-touched files.

-- I'm not sure how to implement this, my guessing is writing a function somehow connecting the access/modified time with 'ls' options?

Comment: Please post separate questions for each of your questions. The answers are likely to be quite different.

Answer (score 1):

[**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) can help.

- For `insert-all-subdir`: Use **`M-+ M-i`** (command `diredp-insert-subdirs-recursive` - menu **Multiple** > **Marked Here and Below** > **Insert Subdirs**).

  If no files or subdirs are marked (and likewise, for any Dired buffers showing any descendent directories), then ***all*** subdirectories and their descendents are inserted.
- To show only the files with a given extension, use **`* .`** (menu **Mark** > **Mark Extension**) to mark the files with the given extension. Then use **`diredp-omit-unmarked`**, to show only the files with that extension. (This is not bound to a key, but is in menu **Mark** > **Omit Unmarked**.)

To highlight files modified later than some date, you can modify the value of variable `diredp-font-lock-keywords-1`.  Remember too that you can easily sort by date etc.  That is usually what people do, to easily see the most recently modified files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these tips. Another ways is to check out sunrise-commander, (which seems to have a lot of functions, -- I'm looking into it)

Comment: My emacs does not have the one your suggested, (**menu Multiple > Marked Here and Below > Insert Subdirs**), possibly you loaded some package I've not? Also, M-+ is not difined in my Emacs here. Seems I've only dired+, dired-details, dired-tar, any other good ones you recommend?

Comment: Are you sure you have **`dired+.el`** (and not just `dired-x.el`, for example)? You should have that menu, if you are using [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) more recent than 2011. Do you have command **`diredp-insert-subdirs-recursive`**? That's the command invoked by that menu item.

Comment: Hi Drew, yes my version was old. So I just updated into the latest version, which has included many more useful features, (like I saw the colorful file lists already, thanks!). 

However, there seems to be bug, **Symbol's function definition is void: toggle-dired-find-file-reuse-dir**, I've tried both the elpa version and github version, this bug exists in both versions. Although I saw the bug report has exists in the emacswiki page, but it's still here. My emacs version is "GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2013-03-13 on bob.porkrind.org
"

Comment: There is *no such function* in **Dired+** or in any of the vanilla Dired files - or in any vanilla Emacs files, as far as I can tell, including in your Emacs version, 24.3.1. ***What code that you are loading*** *is invoking it (and hence raising the error)?* Use non-nil `debug-on-error` to get a backtrace when the error is raised. And what EmacsWiki page are you referring to (and where on that page)?

Comment: This is the command name - note the **`p`** in `diredp`: **`toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir`** (which is an alias for `diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir`). Whatever code is calling it without the `p` needs to be fixed to include the `p`.

Comment: Bug trapped, it's in my configuration -- after update to the latest version of dired+, the 'old' toggle-dired-find-file-reuse-dir has a **p** now, exactly as you suggested. Bow//

Comment: And now I have the **menu Multiple > Marked Here and Below > Insert Subdirs**, perfect. And thanks for the great job in dired+!

Comment: `M-+`: Feel free to use a different prefix key.

Comment: There just come up with another question. Now I learned how to insert all the files in subdir recursively, then how I sort all these files according to their size, so I can pick the first biggest 10? Seems the sorting is still within each sub-dir even after I inserted them.

Comment: Sorting is within each subdir, yes. And a sort *command* (e.g. `s`) applies to the whole Dired buffer - but it does not override any sorting that is caused by `ls` switches that you specify for individual subdirs (e.g. if you use `C-u i` to insert the subdir, and you specify different switches from the main listing).